# 403 error when retrieving site' members

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, error, groups

I am using the SharePoint REST API to retrieve site' members.
However, some sites provide the 403 (Forbidden) error when retrieving members by using the Admin account.

I guess these sites were created by other accounts (Of course the Admin account manages these accounts).

So, do we have any way to retrieve site' members via the admin account?

Comment: Does this user is site collection administrator for all sites?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint admins don't have automatic access to all sites, but they can give themselves access to any site.

You could go to the SharePoint admin center, add yourself as site admins for that site. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-sites-in-new-admin-center